# Generating a ticket ID in a CRM

Tags: java, primary-key, unique, uniqueidentifier

I am wroking on a **help desk system** and did some research before starting work on it. I noticed that all **ticket IDs** start with the current date followed by a few digits. For example, 2012102620000033.

How can this kind of ID be generated in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be to have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For example,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String isoDate = sdf.format(new Date());
// Append your ticket serial number...
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in the other answers was useful... Please check if this helps:

```
Random random = new Random();
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(date.format(new Date()) + String.valueOf(random.nextInt(999999999)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, the ticket ID can be generated using the *[Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)* class API in your source code with the help of functions, and it can concatenated with a timestamp to the string variables.